# How do I install tensorflow with gpu support for Mac?

Tags: tensorflow

My MacBook Pro doesn't have a NVIDIA gpu. So it's not possible to run CUDA. I'm wondering which of the earlier versions of TensorFlow have gpu support for Mac OS? And how can I install on Anaconda?

Answer (score 2):

As stated on the [official](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#top_of_page) site:

> Note: As of version 1.2, TensorFlow no longer provides GPU support on
> Mac OS X.

..so installing any earlier version should be fine. But since your hardware does not have NVIDIA graphics card with CUDA support, it doesn't matter anyway.

In terms of installing TensorFlow on Mac OSX using Anaconda, you can just follow steps nicely described in the official [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)

Comment: The doc doesn't exist! - https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow relies on CUDA for GPU use so you need Nvidia GPU. There's experimental work on adding OpenCL support to TensorFlow, but it's not supported on MacOS.

On anecdotal note, I've heard bad things from people trying to use AMD cards for deep learning. Basically AMD doesn't care about deep learning, they change their interfaces without notice so things break or run slower than CPU.